# Spring MVC: Insert values into all my ModelAndView s

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop

I have a mid-size Spring application and I want to insert key/value pairs into all my ModelAndViews in a cross cutting fashion (much like AOP).

The motivation is to add all kind of data to all my pages (configuration values, build number, etc).

What is the easiest way to have this done? I prefer without AOP but I am ready to use it if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options here.

1. Write a custom `HandlerInterceptor` and [add it to the config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor), and override the `postHandle()` method, adding your data to the supplied `ModelAndView`.
2. If your data is static, then you might be able to add it to the `ViewResolver` using the `attributes` property of `UrlBasedViewResolver`. This is only really useful for static string-based config that you can put into your beans file.
3. Annotated a method in your controller(s) with `@ModelAttribute`. Any object returned by such annotated methods are added to the model automatically. This will only be done for requests handled by `@Requestmapping`-annotated methods in that controller class.

Comment: +1 great, the HandlerInterceptor solution is what I was looking for!